# I entered mvn command in windows, but the command line return a java hint

Tags: java, maven

I have maven 3.3.1 and java 1.7 installed on my machine, windows 8.1.

```
MAVEN_HOME=C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-maven-3.3.1
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75
Path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;
```

I've tried to access mvn command line, under C:\Users\{myusername}>, it works well:

```
C:\Users\{myusername}>java -version
java version "1.7.0_75"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)

C:\Users\{myusername}>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.1 (cab6659f9874fa96462afef40fcf6bc033d58c1c; 2015-03-13T13:10:2
7-07:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-maven-3.3.1\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_75, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: GBK
OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

But when I change the command path to D:, another disk in my machine, the output becomes:

```
D:\>mvn --version
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "server" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is server.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument

    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for m
ore details.

D:\>java -version
java version "1.7.0_75"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

Besides, when I use Intellij to create maven project, just like quickstart, the similar error happened:

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set. Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match.[ERROR] Maven execution terminated abnormally (exit code 1)
```

I've tried like mvn -version, mvn -d. But they still do not work.
Could anyone please help? Thanks!!

Updated:
Now my environment variables is set to:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75;
CLASSPATH=.;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\dt.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;
M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-maven-3.3.1;
MAVEN_HOME=C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-maven-3.3.1;
PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;{others...}
```

And the problem still exists.

Updated:

Whenever I type after mvn command in D: path, the command line will just return java hint; it seems all the things after mvn are ignored.
Just like this:

```
D:\>mvn fewadsfe
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "server" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is server.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument

    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for m
ore details.
```

Comment: How are you setting your environment variables? Also, don't put the jre in the folder `Path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;`

Comment: Yeah, I've deleted the jre folder for the Path environment variables. But the problem still exists...

Comment: Only two things. JAVA_HOME must be set correctly which means for Maven it must point to a JDK. Only the bin folder of `apache-maven-3.3.1/bin` must be in your path. That's all really needed. Afterwards you should run `mvn --version`. You have to close and reopen your console after changing the environment variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue with Maven 3.3.1 but when I tried version 3.2.5 the problem fixed. I don't know what's wrong with windows 7/8 and maven 3.3.1.

Comment: Yes. I think I have change the version with Maven. Thanks!

Comment: Yes same here. Is this version issue with maven on window 8.

Answer (score 11):

I too have this problem with maven 3.3.1 and windows 7 and I have found this [answer](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Problem-Running-Maven-td5833093.html) in a forum. In this version of maven there is a problem with the command line being issued in the root directory of a drive (c:\, d:\, ...). Issuing the command on any other directory works.

Comment: This was also my problem, i was only running mvn -version to verify the path was correct. was about to downgrade when I saw this... thanks

Comment: Yes, I think this really helps! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As stated in previous replies, the problem is with `"-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\"` property. If the quotes around this property are removed, the java command works fine. It seems that the end quote is being treated as part of the path due to preceding backslash.

Adding following line in `mvn.cmd` after `:endDetectBaseDir` tag fixed it for me. I am using maven 3.3.3.

`IF "%MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR:~-1%"=="\" set MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR=%MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR%\`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Windows Server 2012 R2 with Apache Maven 3.6.0. It was a strange issue.

I had to delete **C:\.mvn** Folder and it worked!

[image: With C:.mvn Folder]

[image: Without C:.mvn Folder]

Answer (score 0):

On the other drive you're running the command with `--` instead of `-` which isn't recognized and prints `-help` instead. Make sure you're using

```
mvn -version
```

> -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system property is not set.

This is a known bug (more details [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137783)) which has been **fixed** now. Either update or patch your current installation as described in the bug tracker.

> Fixed in IDEA 14.0.x and 14.1 branches, the fix will be available in
>   14.0.5 and 14.1.1 respectively.
>
> If you want to try the fix right now, do the following:
>
> for **IDEA 14.0.3**:
>
> 1. unzip the archive with the patch from [IDEA-137783-patch-for_IDEA_14.0.3.zip](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/_persistent/IDEA-137783-patch-for_IDEA_14.0.3.zip?file=74-220287&v=0&c=true)
> 2. backup and replace the following jars
>
>    - \plugins\maven\lib\maven.jar
>    - \plugins\maven\lib\maven-server-api.jar
>
>    with jars from the archive
>
> for **IDEA 14.1**:
>
> 1. unzip the archive with the patch from [IDEA-137783-patch-for_IDEA_14.1.zip](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/_persistent/IDEA-137783-patch-for_IDEA_14.1.zip?file=74-220288&v=0&c=true)
> 2. backup and replace the following jars
>
>    - \plugins\maven\lib\maven.jar
>    - \plugins\maven\lib\maven-server-api.jar
>    - \plugins\maven\lib\maven32-server-impl.jar
>
>    with jars from the archive

Comment: Actually I've tried either '-' or '--' on both disks. But the problem still exists.

Comment: What's the output with `-` on `D` drive?

Comment: @NagArvindGudiseva I was just notified that your edit didn't pass the review queue. If you like, you can use this comments section to share your feedback again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had MAVEN_OPTS environment variable incorrectly set up. Which was not in use. That was causing this issue.

After having a look at this exec command in mvn file. I realized something may be wrong with the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable. It worked after deleting that incorrectly set up environment variable.

```
exec "$JAVACMD" \
$MAVEN_OPTS \
$MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS \
-classpath "${CLASSWORLDS_JAR}" \
"-Dclassworlds.conf=${MAVEN_HOME}/bin/m2.conf" \
"-Dmaven.home=${MAVEN_HOME}" \
"-Dlibrary.jansi.path=${MAVEN_HOME}/lib/jansi-native" \
"-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=${MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR}" \
${CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER} "$@"
```

PS - Be careful while deleting the variable. Make sure that same is not being used directly/indirectly anywhere in any other application.