# maven command must be executed on the user path?

Tags: maven

I execute `mvn -v` command on the path "D:",but the output shows

```
 java [-options] class [args...]

 or   java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
```

But i execute the same command on the path "C:\Users\xxx",it runs ok.

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-11T00:41:47+08:00)
Maven home: D:\temp\apache-maven-3.3.3-bin\apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.8.0_65, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre
Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: GBK
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

Comment: This is intriguing. Can you modify the mvn.bat file in Maven home: `D:\temp\apache-maven-3.3.3-bin\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin` and add an `echo on` , then rerun the first version and paste output here please? If the .bat file has an echo off please comment it out as well.

Comment: @AshutoshJindal,I update the maven version to 3.3.9 and the problem is be  resoved,thank you..[same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313030/i-entered-mvn-command-in-windows-but-the-command-line-return-a-java-hint)